# Skype not always loading as a applet in Fluxbox

Tags: skype, fluxbox

I've put `skype &` in my `.fluxbox/startup` file, and Skype indeed does start when I power the computer on. The problem is, it often doesn't load as an applet. You can see what I mean on this screenshot:

[image]

On this rare occasion, it did load up in that little bar, but, as I've said, that happens rarely. It's very weird because Skype does start, its window does show and all, but that small icon (usually) doesn't. Why is that?

This is my startup file:

```
#!/bin/sh

x-terminal-emulator & 
nm-applet &
gnome-sound-applet &
conky & 
batti &
skype &

fbsetbg -f .fluxbox/wallpapers/w1.jpg

exec fluxbox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem with some programs. My answer was to give fluxbox more time to load itself. I am not sure the reasoning is correct, but it has worked before =P

Create a script called `skype-loader` like the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep 10
skype
```

then call it on the fluxbox startup file

```
batti &
/some/path/skype-loader &
```